# How to get the value for a pattern for a range including the pattern

Tags: shell, linux-disk-free

I'm looking to get all the Filesystem including `data` to `data[1-4]`, so while using below i only get the value for range specified like `data1 to data4`, However i'm looking to have `data` as well.

```
[root@dataserver ~]# df -PH /data[1-4]
Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
nfs01:/vol/dataserver_data1  1.4T  713G  608G  54% /data1
nfs01:/vol/dataserver_data2  859G  405G  455G  48% /data2
nfs01:/vol/dataserver_data3  4.7T  3.7T  925G  80% /data3
nfs01:/vol/dataserver_data4  1.1T  252G  769G  25% /data4
```

Below is what i want to be fetched along with another data sets.

```
nfs01:/vol/dataserver_data       2.5T  2.3T  118G  96% /data
```

please advise.

Comment: How about `df -PH /data /data[1-4]`?

Comment: @codeforester, that works as we are giving absolute dat apatterns